# Use Composer library inside Custom Class

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, composer-php

I'm using Doctrine DBAL to connect to my database. I created a custom class to act as a kind of Controller (it's pretty much just for retrieving data). I'm using composer's autoload to load this class, so I place it in /src/Digital/Data.php (using PSR-0). Everything works fine, but now I need to use Doctrine in /src/Digital/Data.php, do I have to put `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`in it? In my index file I also have this (to call the Data class). Which is the proper way to use Doctrine in my custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the ClassLoader only once. The ClassLoader is registered by the `vendor/autoload.php` file. If you already included that file in the index file, there is no need to do that in any other file.

The best practice is to include it in the frontcontroller or bootstrap file.